# Code demo (live) snippets

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Does anyone know how to make a series of code snippets, that can be used in a live code demo scenario??
I have build a complete app, that I want to chunk into snippet pieces, that I can use in a live demo, without unnessesary time of typing/typos the code in live.

Using Visual Studio 2013 btw.

I have done some research for it, but without any leads! Didn't for example know about the drag and drop functionality. All suggestions are appriciated, since I don't know every corner of VS yet (tho why I'm asking, since my google obviously doesn't lead to a useful result).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a full tutorial on how to create Code Snippets for Visual Studio [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms165393%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).
A complete walk through on how to create a code snippet can also be found on the MSDN site [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165394.aspx).

They have also created a [utility](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/3260eed5-c3c2-44f8-b705-a332d3a9f64b) to make it easier to create your own code snippets, a full blog entry about how to use the utility from the VS blog can be found [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2014/01/15/visually-creating-snippets.aspx)

The basics of creating a code snippet are as follows:

1. Create a folder somewhere on your drive that you want to store all your code snippets into
2. Create the different snippet files in this directory (as explained in the links above)
3. Add this directory to your VS's list of snippets by going to *Tools* -> *Code Snippets Manager* (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>k</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>b</kbd>)
4. Create a file with the extension `.snippet` inside this folder and edit the file with the code content that you would like the snippet to be.
5. After reloading you VS you will be able to use the shortcut code snippet that you defined inside your snippet to automatically insert all the code.

You can then share this folder with all your co-workers or trainees and they will all have the same snippets.

A very basic example of the content of a .snippet file for a C# code snippet (Everything inside the CDATA[] will be what your snippet with produce into your editor):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<CodeSnippets xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/2005/CodeSnippet">
  <CodeSnippet Format="1.0.0">
    <Header>
        <Title>Demo Class create</Title>
        <Shortcut>demo1</Shortcut>
    </Header>
    <Snippet>
      <Code Language="CSharp">
        <![CDATA[public class DemoApp
{
  public string GetHellow()
  {
    return "Hello World";
  }
}]]>
      </Code>
    </Snippet>
  </CodeSnippet>
</CodeSnippets>
```

I would highly recommend reading through all the tutorials linked to fully utilise the abilities that the code snippets can provide you while performing your demonstration.

Comment: Curious: Does this also work with Winforms?

Comment: Thats what I ended with. Thanks. Btw, if anyone searching through this, there is an IDE extension called 'Snippet Designer' which can help you export the snippets, instead of typing them all by yourself! :)

Comment: I think that if you where to add two snippets, one for the partial code behind class and one for the partial code behind for the designer section, this could potentially for for WinForms. I tested the code snippet in a WinForms general class, so the snippets themselves work anywhere as long as the language matches

Comment: Sounds good. I don't think I would use it to add/modify controls, though..

Answer (score 2):

Open your toolbox, select code, drag into toolbox.

You can then just drag these snippets from your toolbox as and when you need them.

Comment: Can you add shortcuts to these elements you drag to the toolbox, or can they only be accessed by drag&drop?

Comment: The idea where to start a new solution, so my crowd could follow it from the beginning. But the drag and drop into Toolbox doesn't seems to be shared across solution. Any suggestions?

Comment: If you want something more portable across solutions then look at Bernd Linde's answer for using 'real' code snippets. My solution is the my usual course of action when decomposing a solution into sections I can drag in for a demonstration. You then start from what is essentially an empty solution with a preloaded Toolbox. And no, these can't be added with shortcuts, they are dragged on.

Answer (score 0):

Cant you just put all the code, classes, etc on a separate screen and have your new project on the projected or (live) screen. Then just copy and paste from one to the other?